# Как зациклить анимацию css?

Tags: вёрстка, css3, css-animation

Привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно зациклить css анимацию?

Три картинки меняют друг друга, поворачиваясь по Y.
Проблема в том, что в конце резкое возвращение в начало цикла, т.е. анимация просто начинается с начала, а нужно сделать "петлю".

Для удобства codepen - http://codepen.io/Andrey-m/pen/bpRwEe

Если его посмотреть, все станет понятно, обратите внимание на рывок после конца анимации третьего слайда, происходит как бы рывок в начало на первый.

```css
.banner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 143px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 15px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.side1 {
  animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
.side2 {
  animation: rotate2 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate2 5s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
.side3 {
  animation: rotate3 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate3 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="side1 position">
    <h2>1111111111111111</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="side2 position">
    <h2>2222222222222222</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="side3 position">
    <h2>3333333333333333</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том, что у вас неверная логика анимации была. Конечное положение при анимации и начальное должны совпадать, чего у вас продумано не было. В примере ниже показал примерную логику расчета для таких анимаций. Дальше самостоятельно...

```css
.banner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 143px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.side1 {
  animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  16.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  33.2% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  49.8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  66.4% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  83.0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  99.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  16.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  33.2% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  49.8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  66.4% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  83.0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  99.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
.side2 {
  animation: rotate2 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate2 5s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  16.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  33.2% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  49.8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  66.4% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  83.0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  99.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  16.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  33.2% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  49.8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  66.4% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  83.0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  99.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
.side3 {
  animation: rotate3 5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: rotate3 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  16.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  33.2% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  49.8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  66.4% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  83.0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  99.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  16.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  33.2% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  49.8% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  66.4% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  83.0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  99.6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
      <div class="banner">     
  <div class="side1 position">
    <h2>1111111111111111</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="side2 position">
    <h2>2222222222222222</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="side3 position">    
    <h2>3333333333333333</h2>
  </div>       
      </div>
```